# How to get the match scores for documents queried in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have setup my index in elastic search and have connected kibana to it. In the discover tab when i write a query i get my resulting documents which i know are sorted by a match score by Elasticsearch. How can i access this value in my visualizations? The _score field does not show up in the table format but does show up on clicking the JSON link.

My vision is to present to the user a table based on the query criteria and the option to sort via the _score criteria.Does this make sense?

Eg. for my query

```
first_name : Betty AND last_name: Campbell
```

I get [image]

And the score column is not visible.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
Managed to get the score field :
In the setting tab in Kibana go to the metaFields section and add _score to it. Go back and query your data to see _score column waiting there for you.  But its not propagating to the visuals. And also its not showing very consistent behavior, after a random amount of time it just disappears from the discover tab but is still present in meta.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Discover Tab, you can see the no of matches to your queries as HITS. Hits shows the no of matching results to your query.
It is shown in right side just below the toolbar & above the histogram.

Comment: I dont need the Hits data. That is essentially the results returned by my query. I need the _score field which tells me the relevance of my queries. And i need it to be accessible to my visuals.